# Layer between Entity and DTO

Tags: java

In my project I have Entities and DTO's.
I think I need a layer between those two, because:
Nowadays my DTO's have a lot of methods, because the data must be modified after selected by the database.
Those modifications can't do the database itself.
I've learned, that the DTO's should have any methods and should be used only as a container.

Now I'm thinking about a layer between Entity and DTO, in which the methods will be hold.
At the end of the business code I will map the newly data container into the DTO.

Do you think this is a good practise? Or is it to much overhead and it is preferred to let the methods on the DTO?

How should I name these containers?

```
-- Entity
-- Dto
-- new Layer -> maybe Data?
```

Futhermore I will have the property definitions in all three containers. This isn't so good for extend the project in the future, is it?

Comment: You should consider using Repository than DTO. [Check this out](https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/)

Comment: I already use repositories, but with the constructor expression. The application is only for selecting from database, so I don't use the entities in the business code. Instead I use the DTO's